# StreetViewPanorama moving around without smooth Transitions

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-street-view

If you see their Business Photos homepage they have some nice Automated Virtual Tour using Google Streetview.
http://maps.google.com/help/maps/businessphotos/

If you pause the tour and use the controls to move around, you get the nice transitions from spot to spot.
I'm trying to figure out how to do this.

Here is an example of StreetView in their API and it also DOES NOT have the smooth transitions.
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/streetview-events

I need to do this from the Javascript library and not embed an iframe.

Thanks!